# How to get scanf to work in an if statement objective c

Tags: objective-c, if-statement, scanf

How do you make a scanf work in an if statement? In objective - c

```
    Calculator *myCalculator = [ [ Calculator alloc ] init ] ;

    NSLog(@"What would you like to do: add , subtract, multiply , divide , set accmulator, or exit?") ;
    scanf("%c",  &what[20] ) ;

     if( strcmp(&what[20] , "subtract" ) == 0 )
    {
        NSLog(@"first number:" ) ;
        scanf("%lg" , &value1) ;
        NSLog(@"second number: ") ;
        scanf("%lg" , &value2) ;

        [myCalculator setAccmulator: value1] ;
        [myCalculator subtract: value2] ;
        NSLog(@"%lg" ,[myCalculator accmulator ]) ;
    }
    if( strcmp(&what[20] , "add" ) )
    {
        NSLog(@"first number:" ) ;
        scanf("%lg" , &value1) ;
        NSLog(@"second number: ") ;
        scanf("%lg" , &value2) ;

        [myCalculator setAccmulator: value1] ;
        [myCalculator add: value2] ;
        NSLog(@"%lg" ,[myCalculator accmulator ]) ;

    }
     if( strcmp(&what[20] , "multiply" ) == 0 )
    {
        NSLog(@"first number:" ) ;
        scanf("%lg" , &value1) ;
        NSLog(@"second number: ") ;
        scanf("%lg" , &value2) ;

        [myCalculator setAccmulator: value1] ;
        [myCalculator multiply : value2 ] ;
         NSLog(@"%lg", [myCalculator accmulator ]) ;
    }
     if( strcmp(&what[20] , "divide" ) == 0 )        {
        NSLog(@"first number:" ) ;
        scanf("%lg" , &value1) ;
        NSLog(@"second number: ") ;
        scanf("%lg" , &value2) ;

        [myCalculator setAccmulator: value1] ;
        [myCalculator divide: value2] ;
         NSLog(@"%lg", [myCalculator accmulator ]) ;
    }
     if( strcmp(&what[20] , "set accmulator" ) == 0 )        {
        NSLog(@"enter number you want to set" ) ;
        scanf("%lg" , &value1) ;

        [myCalculator setAccmulator: value1 ] ;
        NSLog(@"%lg" , [myCalculator accmulator] ) ;
    }
    else
        return 0 ;



}

return 0 ;
```

}

and the output doesn't even give you a chance to type anything for the scanf, I have tried removing the { } but it made no difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is here :

`( strcmp(&what[20] , "subtract" )`. This isn't a method result so the  `if` statement doesn't know what this is, therefore it doesn't know what to do with `== 0`.

Try this way :

```
Calculator *myCalculator = [ [ Calculator alloc ] init ] ;

scanf("%c",  &what[20] ) ;

NSString* userInput = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String: &what[20]];
//change "add" to check another NSString
//this way tou don't have to worry wether it's uppercase or lowercase
if ([userInput caseInsensitiveCompare:@"subtract"]==NSOrderedSame) 
{
//check if negative then do whatever
}
```

**NB :**
*== compares the references (addresses of) the strings, and not the value of them.*